# Design Question(s) -Handling template with versions and Interface expose version and type

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, object-oriented-analysis

Does this sounds wrong in design? I am trying to see the most flexible way to handle a template that could get changed over time. For example, with the first version of the application template can have 10 fields. Next version of template can have 15 fields. Issue would not be so much of addition of fields but removal/change of a meaning of field name. The template would be stored as JSON representation. So storing in database with different variations is not a problem. The problem is how best to represent this in OO design principles.
Also, in a classical Spring MVC with JSP views what would the best way to  handle different variations of stored templates over time?

I  was thinking If I store version and Type in database with record(JSON).

To do that  in my base interface(Marker like interface) I have 2 methods String getVersion() and  getType() would that be wrong considering design principles? 
If I do this I can query depending the type for any child class when retrieving those objects from database. Imagine the object is stored as  flat structure(JSON) in database. For example - > findXTypes() as method. In the method implementation I can find by Type='.tostring()' in the query.

It gets complicated when viewing them .I could do this in controller by
 @RequestMapping(value = "/myTemplate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRecord(@RequestParam ...) {
      .... 
         return "myTemplate"+Type + TemplateVersion ;
    }

Then I would have to introduce a new JSP(View) per version. Not great I know, but otherwise I would have to handle the version in IF statements in the same view, which would be more difficult.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to make out what you are asking.  But I think you need to clearly separate the requirements from the design.

I am assuming that your "templates" are actually forms or report pages that you need to present to users.  Or that there is a 1 to 1 relationship between these templates and forms / reports.

Requirements:  You need to support different versions of the form / page over time, and the fields in the page will change over time.  But the key question is whether you need to support multiple versions of the form at any given time?

- If yes, then clearly you need multiple JSPs (or templates, or whatever) with one to represent each version that you *currently* support.
- If no, then you probably should not even *model* the different versions of the template in you code.  Instead, your code base should handle just the current version, and you should use source code version control to represent to store the old versions.

Architecture:  If you need to support multiple version of the template simultaneously, there are two basic approaches:

- Have a single servlet class that handles all versions of the template, and a single view that displays them all.  This should probably be "data driven".  You would store a descriptor for fields to be handled for each template, and code the servlet classes to perform the requests and display the results *solely* based on what is in the descriptors.  (The descriptors could be stored in the database.)

  The problem with this approach is that it is complicated.  And it is more complicated if you need to implement the infrastructure for representing descriptors, processing the information and rendering the results for yourself.
- Write a separate servlet and / or JSP class for each template, and dispatch between them based on (for example) the URL path or parameters.

  The advantage is that this approach is much simpler / easier to implement and understand.  The disadvantage is that there could be a lot of code duplication, most of which probably cant be solved with OO design; i.e. factoring out common code into superclasses.  (JSPs don't support subclassing ...)

Comment: thank you. Yes, will need to support multiple versions of the forms.